# Google Places & Geocode API Authentication for Businesses

Tags: google-maps, authentication, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api, google-geocoder

I'm currently using Google geocoding and place autocomplete services and wanted to push it out to production soon.  For the geocoding service we do authentication via URL signing https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/webservices/auth which works fine.

I tried to apply the same logic to google place autocomplete but it looks like according to their documentation that it will only accept an API key.  Has anyone else run into this issue as well?  Just seems strange that two similar google services would not have the same authentication.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/places/auth

Comment: geocoding auth does generally use an API key, with the exception that "Maps for Work users must include client and signature parameters" because "Requests made without a client ID are not eligible for Maps API for Work benefits". from [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/webservices/#client_id) and [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/?csw=1#api_key)

Comment: So if I understand correctly I have to purchase and use a separate API key just for Places API and use client & signature parameters for the Geocode API? @danyamachine

Comment: no you can generate a key using your existing account. follow the instruction for "authorization" [here](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/index)